# mingw32-make access denied when building wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cmd, wxwidgets, mingw32, building

I get an error when I execute mingw32-make in cmd with the makefile.gcc found in the build\msw folder of the wxWidget decompressed zip. I followed the steps shown in this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/7cw2I9G1QfA).

The error is:

```
make (e=5): Acceso denegado.
mingw32-make: [makefile.gcc:5354: clean] Error 5 (ignored)
```

I tried adding "Everyone" with total control to the security tab in the properties option of the folder in which I had decompressed wxWidgets.

I changed the same option for make.exe file in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

I read that it could be the antivirus, I'm using Windows Defender, I switched off the real time protection but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @ThreeNamesGrace, try rebooting the machine. Then just open command prompt cd  to wxWidgets\build\msw and execute the build command. Don't execute anything else. You probably opened some file that compiler tries to read.

Comment: I rebooted the machine and opened the command prompt and went to wxWidgets\build\msw and executed the same mingw32-make command with all same parameters, even changed SHARED=0 to see if it does something else but the problem is still there.

Comment: @ThreeNamesGrace, can you post the build log or at least couple of last lines of the log? BTW, when you replying - use `@` followed by name of this person. That way (s)he will be notified about the response someone posted...

Comment: @ThreeNamesGrace, did you actually tried to execute clean, or the error shows when you tried to do the building? If you just starting - you don't have anything to clean. So all you need to do is to issue a second command. BTW, a helpful advice - UNICODE options is the default one so you don't have to specify it when building version 3.1+. Also it is always helpful to build `debug` version of the library in the beginning and not the release one. So you command will essentially become `mingw32-exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=1`. However I would simplify the life even further... .

Comment: ...and compile the library as static one so that when it is time to distribute the binaries all you will need is one executable. It will also make the debugging of your program easier because you will not need to copy wxWidgets DLL anywhere - they will be built into the executable. So the command I would use will become `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0`. Keep in mind that you will need to use exactly the same command when building your software or se appropriate configuration when using any kind of IDE. Good luck.

Comment: BTW2 - if you plan to use CodeBlocks there is a great guide about it written by PB and it is linked as a dedicated thread on the wx forum.

Comment: @Igor, actually, I'm using Visual Studio Code, but there aren't many tutorials on how to build wxWidgets for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: There is nothing special needed to use wxWidgets with visual studio code - but you'll almost certainly want to use a separate build tool like CMake or Meson instead of vscode's limited build system.  I wrote about how to do this on linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744151/configure-g-to-build-c-with-wxwidget-library/68746545#68746545).  To extend that to use with windows as well, you just need to add a `if(WIN32)` block and add a few extra search folders.

Comment: @ThreeNamesGrace, my point was that since you receive the error trying to clean something that didn't exist in the first place - its not really surprising. Try to continue issue the command without the `clean` and see if you get any errors from it or the compile will finish successfully.

Comment: @Igor, I already used the command without the clean and it prints the same message.

Comment: @Igor, I used another laptop and it works flawlessly for both with the ```clean``` and without it.

Comment: @Igor, what would be the next step after executing ```mingw32-make``` with makefile.gcc?

Comment: @ThreeNamesGrace, start writing the code. ;-) You can also try to compile and run multiple samples provided with wxWidgets - just do `cd c::\wxWidgets\samples\minimal ` and issue exactly the same command you used when you compiled the library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a fatal error, as indicated by "(ignored)" at the end, so it's not clear what your actual problem is -- does the library get compiled or not?

Second, to debug problems such as this one, you could use the [Process Monitor tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) where you can find out accessing which file exactly triggers this error -- this could give you at least some idea. Without knowing it, it's really impossible to know what goes wrong on your machine.

Comment: I get the same error for a lot of files and it never compiles.

Comment: You can't get exactly the same error, about `clean` target, for many files. Maybe you get some other errors, but then you should show them (too).